# How to set up Google Drive SDK API in my forum?

Tags: google-drive-api

Can you tell me how to set up Google Drive SDK API so that i can fetch the image from google drive to forum with drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={FileID} ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution for your forum is to use Google Drive Website Hosting, using the API, you can put the images in a public directory, and just link them directly from your forum.

[Check here for more information.](https://developers.google.com/drive/publish-site)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am not looking into that for now.Is there any way to do like my question?